# Check whether OpenSSL supports certain curve via header/define in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl, cryptography

I need to check whether OpenSSL supports certain Elliptic Curve(s) via CMake.
While cipher and hash availability may be checked via existence of functions from `openssl/evp.h`, like `check_cxx_symbol_exists("EVP_md4", openssl/evp.h, _openssl_has_md4)`, I don't see a way to do the same for curves.

Do I miss something, or there is no better way than checking the output of `openssl ecparam list_curves`?

*Update*: Since my code doesn't require openssl executable, it would be quite desirable to avoid dependency on it for building.

*Update 2*: thanks to the David's answer ended up with the following module: https://github.com/rnpgp/cmake-modules/blob/master/FindOpenSSLFeatures.cmake

Comment: If there is a program which can list functionality of a framework, then using this program seems to be much preferred way than using `check_cxx_symbol_exists` or similar techniques.

Comment: But what to do in case when executable is not available? Is it a good practice to require executable in addition to library while compiling project?

Comment: Hm, I am not an expert in OpenSSL, but if it is possible to install OpenSSL libraries without the `openssl` executable, then trying to avoid a requirement of that executable looks perfectly reasonable intention. Your could update the question and add that your intention (trying to avoid a requirement to have `openssl` executable installed along with the OpenSSL library). BTW, a downvote is not mine.

Comment: Thanks. Another way I see is to compile some small code snippet which attempts to use needed functions and check it's return code, but seems overcomplication at the moment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code (mostly taken from openssl) lists the available ECs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/objects.h>

int
main ()
{
  int ret = 1;
  EC_builtin_curve *curves = NULL;
  size_t n, crv_len = EC_get_builtin_curves (NULL, 0);

  curves = OPENSSL_malloc((int)sizeof(*curves) * crv_len);
  if (curves == NULL)
    goto end;

  if (!EC_get_builtin_curves (curves, crv_len))
    goto memfree;

  for (n = 0; n < crv_len; n++)
    {
      const char *comment = curves[n].comment;
      const char *sname = OBJ_nid2sn (curves[n].nid);

      if (comment == NULL)
        comment = "CURVE DESCRIPTION NOT AVAILABLE";
      if (sname == NULL)
        sname = "";

      printf ("%s\t%s\n", sname, comment);
    }
  ret = 0;

memfree:
  OPENSSL_free (curves);

end:
  return ret;
}
```

Output on my laptop:

```
$ gcc -Wall -L /usr/lib64 -lcrypto -lssl eclist.c -o eclist
$ ./eclist
secp224r1       NIST/SECG curve over a 224 bit prime field
secp256k1       SECG curve over a 256 bit prime field
secp384r1       NIST/SECG curve over a 384 bit prime field
secp521r1       NIST/SECG curve over a 521 bit prime field
prime256v1      X9.62/SECG curve over a 256 bit prime field
```

The openssl binary gives me the same output:

```
$ openssl ecparam -list_curves
  secp224r1 : NIST/SECG curve over a 224 bit prime field
  secp256k1 : SECG curve over a 256 bit prime field
  secp384r1 : NIST/SECG curve over a 384 bit prime field
  secp521r1 : NIST/SECG curve over a 521 bit prime field
  prime256v1: X9.62/SECG curve over a 256 bit prime field
```

Of course printing the values this way may not be very usefull, but the code can be hopefully the base for a test CMake.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet! Will get back with the link to the whole solution once finished.

Comment: Updated the question with link to the whole solution. Thanks again!